# What is the correct format for wallet.aes.json?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I have a file (wallet.aes.json) which I think it's a Blockchain wallet backup but when I go to [Blockchain import](https://login.blockchain.com/wallet/import-wallet) it says Unknown format.

But here is a clue of whats inside the file

```
{
"address":"008aeexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"crypto" : {
    "cipher" : "aes-128-ctr",
    "cipherparams" : {
        "iv" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "ciphertext" : "dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "kdf" : "scrypt",
    "kdfparams" : {
        "dklen" : 32,
        "n" : 262144,
        "r" : 1,
        "p" : 8,
        "salt" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "mac" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
},
"id" : "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
"version" : 3}
```

I have the decryption password and so many tools have failed, that's why I am starting to think this is not a blockchain wallet backup or maybe it's an Ethereum keystore or something else.

It's from my old hard drive.

thank you

Comment: https://blockchain.info/wallet/wallet-format is not working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What is the correct format for wallet.aes.json?**

It seems Blockchain.info / blockchain.com's custodial wallets have used several different formats.

In the github repository for btcrecover you can find some example wallets used for testing. These are in the [btcrecover/test/test-wallets/](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover/tree/master/btcrecover/test/test-wallets) folder

- `blockchain-unencrypted-wallet.aes.json`
- `blockchain-v0.0-wallet.aes.json`
- `blockchain-v2.0-wallet.aes.json`

---

`blockchain-unencrypted-wallet.aes.json` is in text format:

```
{
    "guid" : "9bb4c672-563e-4806-9012-a3e8f86a0eca",
    "sharedKey" : "728e769e-4c26-4301-a0b8-2db25c564c5a",
    "double_encryption" : true,
    "dpasswordhash" : "ba3b18c73dd213b7c411e91f32e202d68208eca63ffe3e4530e6c19fb1f276a5",
    "options" : {"fee_policy":0,"html5_notifications":false,"logout_time":600000,"tx_display":0,"always_keep_local_backup":false,"transactions_per_page":30,"additional_seeds":[]},
    "keys" : [
{"addr":"1BUoAfr3N6RcH3JArntzoFGfk9hrgU4i5a","priv":"oXndJ0rnJR3XTXAxzIAQvjpYdLD1F5X4aCOVB/lKJzwbdQqcYZ4kH9uHodiYXf+jcDHLItxMh5AaAh76m382/w==","created_time":0,"created_device_name":"javascript_web","created_device_version":"1.0"}
    ]
}
```

---

`blockchain-v0.0-wallet.aes.json` looks like base58 encoded data:

```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```

---

`blockchain-v2.0-wallet.aes.json` is text/json but almost all the data is in what looks like a base58 string.

```
{"pbkdf2_iterations":10000,"version":2,"payload":"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"}
```

---

As you suspected, the data you posted looks like an [Ethereum Keystore file](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/93415). Etherum is off topic here, but see [How do I get the raw private key from my Mist keystore file?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/47135)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://login.blockchain.com/wallet/import-wallet
Drag the wallet file into the area above. Supports blockchain.info (wallet.aes.json) files.Use your passwords and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The blockchain wallet.aes.json file has many different formats depending on when it was created. You have V1 , V2 , V3 and now V4 all different.

The above file you posted seems not to be a blockchain.com/info format but rather geth/mist or any other ERC20 wallet format as the address field indicated its and ERC20 wallet.

You can find out more about their formats from the github https://github.com/blockchain/